# DateTimeFormatter doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, java-8, zoneddatetime

I have to convert date-time string to a zoned date-time object. I used **DateTimeFormatter** to read the pattern. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), the **"Z"** in the pattern can accept format like:

- +/- 0000
- +/- 00:00

But **ZonedDateTime.parse(myDate, formatter)** works only for first case; instead in the second case code generates an exception.

```
Execution exception[[DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-06-22T16:00:00.000+00:00' could not be parsed at index 23]]
```

I'm using Java 8. Example & code:

```
"2020-06-08T12:59:10.288+0000" **work**
"2020-06-08T12:59:10.288+00:00" **doesn't work**

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

ZonedDateTime dateConvertedUTC = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter);
LocalDateTime dateConverted = dateConvertedUTC.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome")).toLocalDateTime();
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specified Z for the timezone so that's why 2020-06-08T12:59:10.288+0000 works.

But if you want to parse 2020-06-08T12:59:10.288+00:00 your format must be.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ");
```

You can find this in the JavaDoc:

> Offset Z: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern
> letters. One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute,
> without a colon, such as '+0130'. The output will be '+0000' when the
> offset is zero. Four letters outputs the full form of localized
> offset, equivalent to four letters of Offset-O. The output will be the
> corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero. **Five**
> **letters outputs the hour, minute, with optional second if non-zero,**
> **with colon.** It outputs 'Z' if the offset is zero. Six or more letters
> throws IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Is it possible to parse an optional colon? Using 1 pattern to parse both format (with and without colon)

Comment: You could try "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ[ZZZZ]" But I didn't test it

Answer (score 1):

You do need to define a format for the date-time string, `2020-06-08T12:59:10.288+00:00`. It is already in the [default format of OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME).

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-06-08T12:59:10.288+00:00");
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Get ZonedDateTime in the desired time-zone from OffsetDateTime
        ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome"));

        // Get LocalDateTime from ZonedDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-08T12:59:10.288Z
2020-06-08T14:59:10.288
```

**Note:** The conversion from `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalDateTime` throws away the valuable information, the time-zone. Therefore, you should perform this conversion only when you are sure that your business logic will not require the time-zone information.

Comment: He does "LocalDateTime dateConverted = dateConvertedUTC.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome")).toLocalDateTime();" so this makes sense as he converts it a Zone

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - The note at the end of my answer is important. One should use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` when dealing with time-zone or offset instead of converting the date-time to `LocalDateTime` which drops off the valuable information of time-zone and offset.

Comment: But in his example it seems that he receives the date with a timezone but wants it to convert in local time. And if you don't need the timezone part why should you keep it. This is often the case in my applications where we store the date in the local timezone. So without timezone

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - It seems both of us are on the same page but just talking about different requirements. You are absolutely right that it makes sense to convert the date-time to `LocalDateTime` when we do not need time-zone and offset information. What I have mentioned is that if we are dealing with time-zone and offset, we should use `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`. :)

Comment: Yes and that's what he  uses "ZonedDateTime dateConvertedUTC = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter);" :-)